# Drawing a polygon in 3d space (and extruding it) using three.js

Tags: three.js

I’m new to three (and, in a way, to 3d in general…) and I need to do something that appear to be way more complicated than I thought… I have two needs :

- Draw a polygon from a set of points
- Extrude that polygon

As an input, I have a set of points in 3d (x, y and z) defining the outline of the polygon and the “depth” of the extrusion. Each point can be anywhere in x/y/z, all aligned on a “plane” (that plane being rotated/moved in space by unknown values beforehand).

I thought it would be relatively easy to create this polygon “in the air” and extrude it in the directions of the polygon’s normals, but I can’t find out how to do it.

As an example, this is a (simple) possible input for my use case. Note that I can have more than 3 points :

```
var polygon = {
    "points":[
        [0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 10, 10], 
        [10, 0, 10]
    ],
    "extrude":5
}
```

As I understand it, Three can only create 2d polygons. I thought of “triangulating” my points from their final 3d position to a 2d plane (and then rotate this “plane” so the points go back to their original position), but I’m not quite sure how to do that and I fear that rounding errors might move my points a bit… Is there a better way? Can someone push me in the right direction?

Comment: See here: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_shapes

Comment: All of those shapes are drawn using Vector2 (in a 2d space). I'd like to draw 2d shapes with Vector3 (placing each points at different x/y/z).

I come from the easier 2d world. With a simple 2d canvas, we can do something like this to create a shape from its points and then fill it. 

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.moveTo(0, 10);
    ctx.moveTo(10, 5);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

I thought I could do something similar (but in 3d). Maybe I'm just not in the right mindset for this...